# jquery Slider - how to calculate percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made use of `var slideWidth = 420;` to specify sliders width and then `$('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);` to calculate all sliders width for long time and it was working fine with pixels

**Problem**

I need to use % and Jquery seems not to understand it.

```
// slider
   var currentPosition = 0;
   var slideWidth = 420; // Use quotes('') for %  
   var slides = $('.slide'); // for each image
   var numberOfSlides = 4; // slides.length: show all images 

   // Remove scrollbar in JS 
   $('.slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

   // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div

   slides.wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>').css({'float' : 'left','width' : slideWidth});

   // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
   /* 
   Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
   #slideInner wraps all of our slides that has a width equal to total width of all .slide div.

   Problem: It needs a fix variable to calculate width    

   */

    $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// slider
var currentPosition = 0;
var slideWidthPct = 80; // this is a percent (between 0 and 100)
var slides = $('.slide'); // for each image
var numberOfSlides = Math.min(4, slides.length); // slides.length: show all images 
var singleSlideWidth = slideWidthPct / numberOfSlides;

// Remove scrollbar in JS 
$('.slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div

slides.wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>').css({'float' : 'left','width' : "" + singleSlideWidth + "%"});

// Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
$('#slideInner').css('width', "" + slideWidthPct + "%");
```

Working example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Bb/3/

Comment: It's almost working but I have a problem: the code, above,  add a `{width:0.25%;}` to images container -> `div.slide` and the scroll is not working right. You can see it at: [Slider Test](http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Bb/1/)

Comment: @Martin - Whoops.  I should not have been dividing by 100.  I updated the code and also changed the numberOfSlides to be slides.length if it is less than 4.  You can decide if that bit works better for you or not.

Comment: @Martin - I also just changed your animate method to set the marginLeft to a % value, since that's what we are calculating now.